# How to improve image segmentation using the watershed?

Tags: java, image, opencv, kotlin, mobile

I am developing an application to detect the lesion area, for this I am using the grabcut to detect the ROI and remove the background from the image. However in some images it is not working well. He ends up not identifying the borders of the region of interest well. The watershed can better identify the edges for this type of work, however I am having difficulties making this transition from grabcut to watershed. Before processing the grabcut, the user uses touchevent to mark a rectangle around the image of interest (wound area) to facilitate the work of the algorithm. As the image below.

[image]

However, using other wound images, segmentation is not good, showing flaws in ROI detection.

Image using grabcut in app

[image]

Image using watershed in desktop

[image]

this is the code:

```
private fun extractForegroundFromBackground(coordinates: Coordinates, currentPhotoPath: String): String {
    // TODO: Provide complex object that has both path and extension

    val width = bitmap?.getWidth()!!
    val height = bitmap?.getHeight()!!
    val rgba = Mat()
    val gray_mat = Mat()
    val threeChannel = Mat()
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, gray_mat)
    cvtColor(gray_mat, rgba, COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
    cvtColor(rgba, threeChannel, COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    threshold(threeChannel, threeChannel, 100.0, 255.0, THRESH_OTSU)

    val rect = Rect(coordinates.first, coordinates.second)
    val fg = Mat(rect.size(), CvType.CV_8U)
    erode(threeChannel, fg, Mat(), Point(-1.0, -1.0), 10)
    val bg = Mat(rect.size(), CvType.CV_8U)
    dilate(threeChannel, bg, Mat(), Point(-1.0, -1.0), 5)
    threshold(bg, bg, 1.0, 128.0, THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    val markers = Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_8U, Scalar(0.0))
    Core.add(fg, bg, markers)

    val marker_tempo = Mat()
    markers.convertTo(marker_tempo, CvType.CV_32S)

    watershed(rgba, marker_tempo)
    marker_tempo.convertTo(markers, CvType.CV_8U)

    val imgBmpExit = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    Utils.matToBitmap(markers, imgBmpExit)

    image.setImageBitmap(imgBmpExit)


    // Run the grab cut algorithm with a rectangle (for subsequent iterations with touch-up strokes,
    // flag should be Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)
    //Imgproc.grabCut(srcImage, firstMask, rect, bg, fg, iterations, Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

    // Create a matrix of 0s and 1s, indicating whether individual pixels are equal
    // or different between "firstMask" and "source" objects
    // Result is stored back to "firstMask"
    //Core.compare(mark, source, mark, Core.CMP_EQ)

    // Create a matrix to represent the foreground, filled with white color
    val foreground = Mat(srcImage.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, Scalar(255.0, 255.0, 255.0))

    // Copy the foreground matrix to the first mask
    srcImage.copyTo(foreground, mark)

    // Create a red color
    val color = Scalar(255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0)
    // Draw a rectangle using the coordinates of the bounding box that surrounds the foreground
    rectangle(srcImage, coordinates.first, coordinates.second, color)

    // Create a new matrix to represent the background, filled with black color
    val background = Mat(srcImage.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, Scalar(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

    val mask = Mat(foreground.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1, Scalar(255.0, 255.0, 255.0))
    // Convert the foreground's color space from BGR to gray scale
    cvtColor(foreground, mask, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    // Separate out regions of the mask by comparing the pixel intensity with respect to a threshold value
    threshold(mask, mask, 254.0, 255.0, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    // Create a matrix to hold the final image
    val dst = Mat()
    // copy the background matrix onto the matrix that represents the final result
    background.copyTo(dst)

    val vals = Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3, Scalar(0.0))
    // Replace all 0 values in the background matrix given the foreground mask
    background.setTo(vals, mask)

    // Add the sum of the background and foreground matrices by applying the mask
    Core.add(background, foreground, dst, mask)

    // Save the final image to storage
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(currentPhotoPath + "_tmp.png", dst)

    // Clean up used resources
    firstMask.release()
    source.release()
    //bg.release()
    //fg.release()
    vals.release()
    dst.release()

    return currentPhotoPath
}
```

Exit:

[image]

How do I update the code to use watershed instead of grabcut?

Comment: It's so annoying to read posts this long. You can improve the formatting by resizing the images using markdown tags, like: `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmzwj.png" width="210" height="150"> `

Comment: @karlphillip sorry, i didn't know that. I will correct.

Answer (score 2):

A description of how to apply the watershed algorithm in OpenCV is [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/02/watershed-opencv/), although it is in Python. The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/dbd/tutorial_distance_transform.html) also contains some potentially useful examples. Since you already have a binary image, all that's left is to apply the Euclidean Distance Transform (EDT) and the watershed function. So instead of `Imgproc.grabCut(srcImage, firstMask, rect, bg, fg, iterations, Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)`, you would have:

```
Mat dist = new Mat();
Imgproc.distanceTransform(srcImage, dist, Imgproc.DIST_L2, Imgproc.DIST_MASK_3); // use L2 for Euclidean Distance 
Mat markers = Mat.zeros(dist.size(), CvType.CV_32S);
Imgproc.watershed(dist, markers); # apply watershed to resultant image from EDT
Mat mark = Mat.zeros(markers.size(), CvType.CV_8U);
markers.convertTo(mark, CvType.CV_8UC1);
Imgproc.threshold(mark, firstMask, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY + Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU); # threshold results to get binary image
```

The thresholding step is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294859/how-to-define-the-markers-for-watershed-in-opencv). Also, optionally, before you apply `Imgproc.watershed`, you may want to apply some morphological operations to the result of EDT i.e; dilation, erosion:

```
Imgproc.dilate(dist, dist, Mat.ones(3, 3, CvType.CV_8U));
```

If you're not familiar with morphological operations when it comes to processing binary images, the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) contains some good, quick examples.

Comment: Daniel, I did as you suggested, but I had a mistake. For better viewing I updated the code and the error in the question.

Comment: Ah sorry - the `distanceTransform` function expects a grayscale image, so that line should change from `Imgproc.distanceTransform(srcImage, dist, Imgproc.DIST_L2, Imgproc.DIST_MASK_3);` to `Imgproc.distanceTransform(threeChannel, dist, Imgproc.DIST_L2, Imgproc.DIST_MASK_3);`, as it looks like `threeChannel` is the RGB image converted to grayscale in your code (`Imgproc.cvtColor(srcImage, threeChannel, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)`)

Comment: Daniel, now it was another error in the watershed line (dist, markers), I updated the code and the error in the question. Another doubt Daniel, the rest of the code I just comment on the grabcut line and the rest is like this?

Comment: The error occurs here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/segmentation.cpp#L161. It appears that `dist` isn't the correct type - try adding `dist.convertTo(dist, CvType.CV_8UC3);` after `Imgproc.distanceTransform(threeChannel, dist, Imgproc.DIST_L2, Imgproc.DIST_MASK_3);`

Comment: Daniel, I managed to solve the problem. She can already recognize some regions of the wound, but how do I use the coordinates I got from the user so that the watershed works only in the coordinate area? I updated the code and the output.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - you should be able to instantiate a Mat from `rgba` and  `rect` - something like `Mat subregion = new Mat(rgba, rect)`, similar to what's described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35666255/get-a-sub-image-using-opencv-java and operate on that matrix instead of `rgba`.

Comment: daniel, you can still help me, i didn't get the result i wanted.

Comment: Okay - did you try what I commented above? Also I think this may warrant a new question.

Comment: @danielcahall can you help me out from this Error..
 Caused by: java.lang.Exception: std::exception: std::bad_alloc

This Error occur on this line
 Imgproc.grabCut(srcImage, firstMask, rect, bgModel, fgModel, iterations, Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)